# MailHog or MailCatcher Server setting

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, mailcatcher

I have to automate sending mail and check whether they have been delivered as expected. Inorder to do that i am using mailHog(similar to mailCatcher). I have installed them but i don't know how to make my application send mail to this service instead of normal email sending.

They say that you have to configure your SMTP port to 1025 instead of 25(default). Even after this i am not able to capture those sent mails. Do i need to change my outgoing server name or what else should i do??

This is my web.config file code:

```
<add key="SmtpServerPort" value="1025" />
<add key="SmtpEmailServer" value="BLRCSWEXV01.in.corp.xxxx.com" />
```

PS: I am using protractor to write E2E tests. And i dont want to use mailListener, because it slows my test drastically and even it is not able to capture the mails

Comment: You can also use mailsnag.com for it and don’t worry setting it up locally

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed MailHog on BLRCSWEXV01.in.corp.xxxx.com or is it on an other machine? You need to point both, the server and the port to your MailHog instance.